# Alljoyn compilation error

Tags: linux, alljoyn

please can you help

I'm trying to set the CROSS_COMPILE flag as below

export CROSS_COMPILE=~/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

and I'm getting the following error?

```
$:~/alljoyn/src/alljoyn-16.04.00-src$ scons CPU=arm OS=linux BINDINGS=c,cpp WS=off
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++11 flag... (cached) yes
Using OpenSSL crypto
Building bindings: cpp, c
Building services:
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping common unit test build
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping About Service unit test build
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping alljoyn_core unit test build
SQLITE_DIR not specified: skipping Security Manager sample program build
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping alljoyn_c unit test build
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
        [CC]      alljoyn_c/test/bbcclient.c
        [CXX]     alljoyn_c/src/AboutData.cc
        [CXX]     common/crypto/openssl/CryptoAES.cc
In file included from common/crypto/openssl/CryptoAES.cc:35:0:
common/crypto/openssl/OpenSsl.h:25:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/aes.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/linux/arm/debug/obj/common/crypto/CryptoAES.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I've even set the OPENSSL folder as follows

```
export OPENSSL_ROOT=/home/alljoyn/deps/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the compile parameter as CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

And you need to install some dependencies:

sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install maven

sudo apt-get install scons

sudo apt-get install git

sudo apt-get install curl

sudo apt-get install openssl

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

sudo apt-get install libjson0

sudo apt-get install libjson0-dev

You can refer to this link for more information:
https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/30cfa7dfb041c12e6ba3